# How can I extract only the initial description of a javadoc comment and ignore the javadoc tags using python?

Tags: python, regex, nlp, javadoc

I am trying to extract the text in a Javadoc before the Javadoc tags in python. I have so far been able to avoid the parameter tag, but there are other Javadoc tags that could be mentioned all at once. Is there a better way to do this?

```
parameterTag = "@param"
if (parameterTag in comments):
        splitComments = subsentence.split(my_string[my_string.find(start) + 1: my_string.find(parameterTag)])
```

Input:

```
/**
     * Checks if the given node is inside the graph and
     * throws exception if the given node is null
     * @param a single node to be check
     * @return true if given node is contained in graph,
     *         return false otherwise
     * @requires given node != null
     */
    public boolean containsNode(E node){
        if(node==null){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        if(graph.containsKey(node)){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Output:

```
/**
     * Checks if the given node is inside the graph and
     * throws exception if the given node is null
         */
    public boolean containsNode(E node){
        if(node==null){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        if(graph.containsKey(node)){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Do you want to consider using regex? I mean, the general format is 

    * @[letters] [text]

Comment: Sure! Could you tell me how? I am a beginner at regex, so might need some more details :D Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following your logic, there is a **description part** followed by a **"tags" part**, and then a **closing comment mark**.

If you check line by line an occurrence of tag keyword, you won't be able to deal with this line:

```
     *         return false otherwise
```

Hence, you need to detect if you entered in of exited from a tags part. Below a working example:

```
import re

# Javascript content loading
JSF = open("your_js_file.js", 'r')

js_content = JSF.read()

# We split the script into lines, and then we'll loop through the array
lineiterator = iter(js_content.splitlines())

# This boolean marks if we are or not in a "tags" part
in_tags = False

for line in lineiterator:
    # If we matched a line with a word starting with "@",
    # Then we entered into a "tags" section
    if re.search("@\w+", line) is not None :
        in_tags = True
    # If we matched a closing comment mark, then we left
    # The "tags" section (or never entered into it)
    if re.search("\*/",line) is not None:
        in_tags = False
    if not in_tags:
        print(line)
```